# Angular RxJs: Get last value from anyControl.valueChanges- similar to BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I use valueChanges to view changes of a particular control.
The problem starts when I get the control value as `@Input`, and initialize it in `ngOnChanges`.
If I watch it using `async` pipe,
It does not work.

I imagine, that this is because `ngOnChanges` occurs before `ngOnInit`,
Then the "subscription" to observable is made after the initial boot.
The question is how to solve this.
Can valueChanges act as BehaviorSubject?
Or does anyone have another idea?

This is my code:

**component.ts:**

```
@Input() customerId;
customerState$: observable<number>;
myForm:FormGroup;

constructor(){
 this.customerState$= this.myForm.controls.customerId.valueChanges;
}

ngOnChanges(){
     if (changes.customerId) {
        this.myForm.controls.customerId.setValue(changes.customerId.currentValue);
      }
}
```

**component.html:**

```
{{customerState$|async}}
```

For the first time, it shows nothing.
Only with another change of customeId the value is displayed.

I will note that my code does not really look like this, and my requirement is a little more complicated,
Just to illustrate the problem I created something conceptually similar.

So I would love an answer to the question I asked, and not a specific trick that would solve the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found!
The solution lies in the operator of rxjs.
I did not fully understand, but it works!
If anyone would like to comment on this I would love to hear.

```
constructor(){
 this.customerState$= this.myForm.controls.customerId.valueChanges.pipe(
  shareReplay(1)
);
}
```

Comment: You are right. Just in the moment i prepare my answer for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qkhigq?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

shareReplay(1) will cache the last emitted value. Since the value-change is done BEFORE the async-pipe subscription is setup (input changes may occur before the template is initialized), you need to cache this value to show it in your async pipe subscription.

Comment: @enno.void Thanks for the goodwill!
Apparently sometimes you just need to know what you are asking, in order to find the answer yourself ...